# Can "x exclusive" and/or "x-exclusive" mean that x is excluded?

Tags: word-usage

Is it reasonable for the statement "y is x exclusive" to mean "y does not include the patronage of x"? For instance, is it correct to say that a "members-only" lounge is guest exclusive? If not, would "y is x exclusive" mean?

I understand that you can say that a discount is [brand] exclusive, and mean that the discount is and only is available with/at that brand, but this isn't quite the same situation and unfortunately I'm having a hard time looking for usage that isn't of this variety.

I'm hesitant to accept that the only definition of "x exclusive" is such that "y is x exclusive" implies that "y is x inclusive".

If "exclusive" is the improper word here, would a word like "exclusionary" be more acceptable?

Comment: I'd forget about potentially ambiguous ***X-exclusive*** and stick with ***X-only***, [same as everyone else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whites-only+lunch%2Cwhites-exclusive+lunch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhites%20-%20only%20lunch%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "the water fountain was black people exclusive" is not idiomatic, so it's hard to say for certain what it would mean.

However, it's more likely to imply the opposite of what you intend. Consider this very similar looking phrase:

> CNN Exclusive: New documents reveal behind-the-scenes clash over spending inside Trump inaugural committee [meaning this story is exclusively being reported by CNN]

https://www.cnn.com/2019/08/15/politics/trump-inauguration-spending-subpoena-investigation/index.html

This example uses *exclusive* as a noun, which *Merriam-Webster* defines thus:

> **exclusive** noun
>
> : something exclusive: such as
> **a** : a news story at first released to or reported by only one source
> **b** : an exclusive right (as to sell a particular product in a certain area)

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exclusive

Given the existence of this very similar sounding phrase, your adjective phrase will likely be considered a mistake, and even if not, we would probably read "the water fountain is black people exclusive" as *the water fountain may be used exclusively by black people*.

Comment: So after writing this question, I've realized I overlooked an recent use of "x-**exclusionary**" to mean that x is excluded: ["trans-exclusionary radical feminist"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TERF). So, I was wondering: do you suppose that "the water found was black-people-**exclusionary**" would be interpreted as "the water fountain may not be used by black people"?

Comment: Yes, it probably would be interpreted that way @Ruzihm. I would not recommend using that phrase, though. It's harder to parse and no more informative than "a whites-only water fountain" or "the water fountain was only for white people." There might be other contexts where *[noun]-exclusionary* makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing 'Exclu**sive**' with '[Exclu**ded**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exclude)'.

"A "whites-only" drinking fountain was black people exclusive."  means the opposite of what [I think] you are trying to say:

"The "whites-only" fountain was *for the exclusive use of* black people.", that is, it was ONLY for black people.

[Exclusive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exclusive): limited to only one person or group of people, or expensive and only for people who are rich or of a high social class

I think you will need to re-word this to something like:

"Black people were prohibited from using a "whites-only" drinking fountain." or

"A "whites-only" drinking fountain was for the exclusive use of white people."